# prove that the lesbesque measure of the Cantor set is 0

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

the cantor set is constructed by removing the middle part of the previous cantor sets. So
$C_1 = [0,\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$

$C_2 = [0, \frac{1}{9}] \cup [\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3}] \cup[\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{9} ] \cup [\frac{8}{9},1]$

....

and $C = \cap C_n$

So far i've tried it like this:

Define $D_n = [0,1] \backslash C_n$ and $D = \cup D_n$.

Notice that $[0,1]\backslash C = D$

So what i've tried is constructing a increasing sequence $A_1 = D_1 \dots A_{j+1} = D_{j+1}\backslash D_{j}$, obviously $A_i$ are disjunct so i can use the continuity of measures for below. but now we see:

$\mu(D) = \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_j)$

so we get :

$\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_j) = \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\mu(D_{j}\backslash D_{j-1})$.

and here i'm a little bit stuck, anyone any thoughts on how i get to the magic number 1?

Kees

Comment: Hint: Compute the first few values of $\mu(C_n)$ and watch the miracle happen.

Comment: ah, i get $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ for C that is 3.... that's nowhere near 0 xD

Comment: No, one does not get that for $\mu(C)$.

Comment: omg of course i see now what i did wrong -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $C \subseteq C_n$ for all $n$, $\mu(C) \le \mu(C_n)$ for all $n$. Now since $\mu(C_n) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ for all $n$, we have $\mu(C) \le \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Hence, $\mu(C) = 0$.

Comment: i see this is easier then what i tried, is it possible with the method i tried above. Where i defined the D's, i do not see where that goes wrong.

Comment: @Kees yes, your method will work. At the end, note that $\mu(D_j\setminus D_{j-1}) = \mu(D_j) - \mu(D_{j-1})$ since $D_{j-1} \subset D_j$ and $\mu(D_j) = 1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^j$.

Comment: hahahahaha you're real smart answering all my questions xD, thanks man!

Comment: @Kees no problem!

Comment: oops i see a problem here, $\mu(D_j \backslash D_{j-1}) = \mu(D_j)- \mu(D_{j-1}) = -(2/3)^j + (2/3)^{j-1} = (1/3)(2/3)^{j-1}$ I don't see this going to 1.

Comment: @Kees you're supposed to take $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \mu(D_j\setminus D_{j-1})$, not $\lim_{j\to \infty} \mu(D_j\setminus D_{j-1})$.